# The maximum amount of data that can be store in each session storage, local storage and IndexedDB (Android/PC Firefox)?

Tags: session, storage, local, indexeddb

Can you help me about that!?
Maybe write a simple code to calculate maximum amount of data of session storage, local storage and IndexedDB!?

Note: excute it on Android/PC firefox.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IndexedDB**

The limit for Firefox on desktop is 50MB. After the 50MB it will ask for permissions. When the user accepts it, it is changing to unlimited storage.
Almost the same applies for Firefox on Android where it asks for permission on 5MB and after that it will ask for permission.
Chrome allows up to the requested quota and IE will ask for permission at 10 and 250mb.

**Local Storage**

This is the same for Firefox on android or desktop, both 10MB.
Other browsers like Chrome and IE also have 10MB.

You can find more info here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/quota-research/
A demo application to test this can be found here: [BrowserStorageAbuser](https://github.com/agektmr/BrowserStorageAbuser) (Same as used in the article)